# Why can I not pickle my case classes? What should I do to solve this manually next time?

Tags: jvm, scala.js, akka-http, scala-pickling

#### Edit 2: Observations and questions

1. I am pretty sure along with the commenter below Justin that the problem is due to an errant `build.sbt` configuration. However, this is the first time I have seen an errant `build.sbt` configuration that literally works for *everything* else *except* for pickers. Maybe that is becaus they use macros and I as a rule avoid them.
2. Why would it matter whether `Flow.merge` is used vs `Flow.map` if the problem is with the `sbt`?
3. **Suspicious build.sbt extract**

   `lazy val    server = project
     .dependsOn(sharedJvm, client)`
4. **Suspicious stack trace**

So this is the top of the stack: it goes from a method I cannot find to the linking environment to the string encoding utils. Ok.

```
server java.lang.RuntimeException: stub
```

Huh? `stub`?

```
server  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
server  at scala.scalajs.runtime.package$.linkingInfo(package.scala:143)
server  at scala.scalajs.runtime.package$.environmentInfo(package.scala:137)
```

HUH?

```
server  at scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic$.global(Dynamic.scala:78)
```

???

```
server  at boopickle.StringCodec$.encodeUTF8(StringCodec.scala:56)
```

#### Edit 1: My big and beautiful build.sbt might be the problem

What you cannot see is that I organized in my `project` folder:

- `JvmDependencies.scala` which has regular Jvm dependencies
- `SjsDependencies.scala` which has `Def.settingsKey`s of `libraryDependencies` on `JsModuleID`s
- `WebJarDependencies.scala` which has javascripts and css's

#### build.sbt

```
lazy val    shared = (crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure) in file("shared"))
  .configure(_.enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin))
  .settings(SjsDependencies.pickling.toSettingsDefinition(): _*)
  .settings(SjsDependencies.tagsAndDom.toSettingsDefinition(): _*)
  .settings(SjsDependencies.css.toSettingsDefinition(): _*)

lazy val sharedJvm = shared.jvm
lazy val  sharedJs = shared.js

lazy val    cmdlne = project
  .dependsOn(sharedJvm)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= (
      JvmDependencies.commandLine ++
      JvmDependencies.logging     ++
      JvmDependencies.akka        ++
      JvmDependencies.serialization
    )
  )

lazy val    client = project
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin, SbtWeb, SbtSass)
  .dependsOn(sharedJs)
  .settings(
    (SjsDependencies.shapeless ++ SjsDependencies.audiovideo ++ SjsDependencies.databind ++ SjsDependencies.functional ++ SjsDependencies.lensing ++ SjsDependencies.logging ++ SjsDependencies.reactive).toSettingsDefinition(),
    jsDependencies ++= WebjarDependencies.js,
    libraryDependencies ++= WebjarDependencies.notJs,
    persistLauncher in Compile := true
  )

lazy val    server = project
  .dependsOn(sharedJvm, client)
  .enablePlugins(SbtNativePackager)
  .settings(

    copyWebJarResources := { streams.value.log("Copying webjar resources")
      val `Web Modules target directory` = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "assets"
      val `Web Modules source directory` = (WebKeys.assets in Assets in client).value / "lib"

      final class UsefulFileFilter(acceptable: String*) extends FileFilter {

        // TODO ADJUST TO EXCLUDE JS MAP FILES
        import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
        def accept(file: File) = (file.isDirectory && FileUtils.listFiles(file, acceptable.toArray, true).nonEmpty) || acceptable.contains(file.ext) && !file.name.contains(".js.")
      }

      val `file filter` = new UsefulFileFilter("css", "scss", "sass", "less", "map")

      IO.createDirectory(`Web Modules target directory`)
      IO.copyDirectory(source = `Web Modules source directory`, target = `Web Modules target directory` / "script")
      FileUtils.copyDirectory(`Web Modules source directory`, `Web Modules target directory` / "style", `file filter`)
    },

    // run the copy after compile/assets but before managed resources
    copyWebJarResources <<= copyWebJarResources dependsOn(compile in Compile, WebKeys.assets in Compile in client, fastOptJS in Compile in client),
    managedResources in Compile <<= (managedResources in Compile) dependsOn copyWebJarResources,

    watchSources <++= (watchSources in client),


    resourceGenerators in Compile <+= Def.task {
      val files = ((crossTarget in(client, Compile)).value ** ("*.js" || "*.map")).get
      val mappings: Seq[(File,String)] = files pair rebase((crossTarget in(client, Compile)).value, ((resourceManaged in  Compile).value / "assets/").getAbsolutePath )
      val map: Seq[(File, File)] = mappings.map { case (s, t) => (s, file(t))}
      IO.copy(map).toSeq
    },

    reStart <<= reStart dependsOn (managedResources in Compile),

    libraryDependencies ++= (
      JvmDependencies.akka                ++
      JvmDependencies.jarlocating         ++
      JvmDependencies.functional          ++
      JvmDependencies.serverPickling      ++
      JvmDependencies.logging             ++
      JvmDependencies.serialization       ++
      JvmDependencies.testing
    )
  )
```

#### Edit 0: A very obscure chat thread has a guy saying what I am feeling: no, not **** scala, but

> Mark Eibes @i-am-the-slime Oct 15 2015 09:37
>   @ochrons I'm still fighting. I can't seem to pickle anything anymore.
>   https://gitter.im/scala-js/scala-js/archives/2015/10/15

I have a rather simple requirement - I have one web socket route on a `akka` http server that is defined `AkkaServerLogEventToMessageHandler()`:

```
object AkkaServerLogEventToMessageHandler
  extends Directives {

  val sourceOfLogs =

    Source.actorPublisher[AkkaServerLogMessage](AkkaServerLogEventPublisher.props) map {
      event ⇒
        BinaryMessage(
          ByteString(
            Pickle.intoBytes[AkkaServerLogMessage](event)
          )
        )
    }

  def apply(): server.Route = {
    handleWebSocketMessages(
      Flow[Message].merge(sourceOfLogs)
    )
  }

}
```

This fits into a tiny set of routes in the most obvious way.

Now why is that I cannot get `boopickle`, `upickle`, or `prickle` to serialize something as simple as this stupid case class?

```
sealed case class AkkaServerLogMessage(
                                 message:   String,
                                 level:     Int,
                                 timestamp: Long
                               )
```

- No nesting
- All primitive types
- No generics
- Only three of them

### These all produced roughly the same error

- Using all three of the common picklers to write
- Using `TextMessage` instead of `BinaryMessage` and the corresponding `upickle` or `prickle` `writeJs` or whatever methods
- Varying the `case class` down to nothing (nothing, as in no members)
- Varying the input itself to the `case class`
- Importing various permutations of `Implicits` and underscore stuff

#### ... specifically, they gave me variations on the same stupid error (not the same error, but considerably similar)

```
server [ERROR] [04/21/2016 22:04:00.362] [app-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(app)] WebSocket handler failed with stub
server java.lang.RuntimeException: stub
server  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
server  at scala.scalajs.runtime.package$.linkingInfo(package.scala:143)
server  at scala.scalajs.runtime.package$.environmentInfo(package.scala:137)
server  at scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic$.global(Dynamic.scala:78)
server  at boopickle.StringCodec$.encodeUTF8(StringCodec.scala:56)
server  at boopickle.Encoder.writeString(Codecs.scala:338)
server  at boopickle.BasicPicklers$StringPickler$.pickle(Pickler.scala:183)
server  at boopickle.BasicPicklers$StringPickler$.pickle(Pickler.scala:134)
server  at boopickle.PickleState.pickle(Pickler.scala:511)
server  at shindig.clientaccess.handler.AkkaServerLogEventToMessageHandler$$anonfun$1$Pickler$macro$1$2$.pickle(AkkaServerLogEventToMessageHandler.scala:35)
server  at shindig.clientaccess.handler.AkkaServerLogEventToMessageHandler$$anonfun$1$Pickler$macro$1$2$.pickle(AkkaServerLogEventToMessageHandler.scala:35)
server  at boopickle.PickleImpl$.apply(Default.scala:70)
server  at boopickle.PickleImpl$.intoBytes(Default.scala:75)
server  at shindig.clientaccess.handler.AkkaServerLogEventToMessageHandler$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaServerLogEventToMessageHandler.scala:35)
server  at shindig.clientaccess.handler.AkkaServerLogEventToMessageHandler$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaServerLogEventToMessageHandler.scala:31)
```

### This worked

- Not using `Flow.merge` (defeats the purpose, I want to keep sending out put with logs)
- Using a static value
- Other useless things

### Appeal

Please let me know where and why I am stupid... I spent four hours on this problem today in different forms, and it is driving me nuts.

Comment: you should untag this from java, java and scala are different languages.

Comment: My mistake. I am using it but not in this part.

Comment: Well, isn't it the case that both Akka and the pickling libs are commonly used in Java projects?

Comment: the JVM tag would be much more accurate

Comment: You should probably include your build.sbt, because something looks *very* weird here.  You say that this is running in akka-http (which I assume means server-side), but the error refers to scalajs.js.Dynamic (which is strictly client-side).  So I suspect the problem has nothing to with with the picklers or case classes and everything to do with sbt config...

Comment: @JustinduCoeur you are spot on that seems to be the thread the quoted guy above went down... I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.sbt`, you have:

```
lazy val shared = (crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure) in file("shared"))
  .configure(_.enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin))
```

Do not do this. You must not enable the Scala.js plugin on a cross-project, ever. This also adds it to the JVM side, which will wreak havoc. Most notably, this will cause `%%%` to resolve the Scala.js artifacts of your dependencies in the JVM project, and that is really bad. This is what causes your issue.

`crossProject` already adds the Scala.js plugin to the JS part, and only that one. So simply remove that `enablePlugins` line.

Comment: Good to know. I just started doing that recently, and now I know better

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved. Thanks to @Justin du Coeur for pointing me in the right direction.

The reason `boopickle` wasn't working in particular was because in the dependency chain I was including both the `sjs` and the `jvm` version of `boopickle` in the `server` project.

I removed the `server` `dependsOn` for `client` and for `sharedJs` and also removed `boopickle` from the shared dependencies. Now it works.